# Running report on Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I created report in Report Builder, based on Data Source, using sql query.

[image]

I can run it in Report Builder, but when I upload it and try to run it on Sharepoint, I get error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Semantic query compilation failed: e InvalidSemanticQuery The semantic
>   query is not valid. Details: Data at the root level is invalid. Line
>   1, position 1. ( ''). (rsSemanticQueryEngineError)

Comment: To which file does this lead you? Can you show us the contents of it? At least the beginning? This looks like malformed xml.

Comment: I get only abbove error. I use only SQL query, without any XML.